# Retrieve id of an entity based on which the stream is being mapped

Tags: java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to construct a stream pipeline which is not really straightforward and it gets me puzzled.

The idea is that I have a class containing a set of entities I want to traverse. `Application` class defines a field `Set<Document> documents`. Inside of these docs I have a field `DocumentFile documentFile`. I filter the stream based on the name of this document file, but the result that I need is the id of `Document` entity.

So the method goes like this:

```
private long retrieveSmth(String docName, long applicationId) {
    final Application application = this.applicationDao.get(applicationId);
    final long docId = application.getDocuments()
                                  .stream()
                                  .map(Document::getDocumentFile)
                                  .filter(doc -> doc.getDocumentFileName().equals(docName))
                                  ...
}
```

At this point I get stuck questioning myself how do I get the control back to `Document` level and retrieve the id of the document whose document file satisfies the condition. Is there a way to do this using Stream API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you `map()` to `DocumentFile` you cannot "go back" to the owner object of `DocumentFile` : the `Stream<Document>` was transformed into a `Stream<DocumentFile>`.
You should so not map and specify the object to test from `Stream<Document>.filter()` :

```
final long docId = application.getDocuments()
                              .stream()
                              .filter(doc -> doc.getDocumentFile().getDocumentFileName().equals(docName))
                              .map(Document::getId); // now it is possible
```

Note that you should avoid talking to strangers and this makes this bad smell :

```
doc.getDocumentFile().getDocumentFileName()
```

So it would be interesting to introduce a method `matchesName()` in `Document` that does the delegation and the equality test :

```
public boolean matchesName(String name){
      return name.equals(getDocumentFile().getDocumentFileName());
}
```

In this way it sounds better :

```
.filter(doc -> doc.matchesName(docName))
```

Comment: Or even better, a method that checks if a given name matches, i.e. `public boolean matchesName(String name) { return name.equals(getDocumentFile().getDocumentFileName()); }`, then you use it in the lambda expression: `.filter(doc -> doc.matchesName(docName))`

Comment: @Federico Peralta Schaffner  I love the idea. Meaningful code is all what we need. I updated with :)

Comment: Oh wow simplicity is genius! Thanks a lot. I don't know why I made it so complicated. Thanks for additional refactoring tips, guys!